# Need help working around a problem with std::thread::join() on NXP Linux

Tags: c++, multithreading, embedded-linux, glibc

I have a program that creates a number of threads, then joins to them when they terminate.  On AWS/X86/Ubuntu, the program works fine.  On NXP/ARM Distro 5.10, it sometimes works and frequently hangs in the join.  When it hangs, the threads are gone, but the main program is pegged at 100%.  Normally, the main thread consumes no CPU.

Here's the program:  I build with `g++ --std=c++11 -O3`.

```
// Generate load and then be idle, do it until killed with different loading
// patterns.  Also, have several threads.

#include <sys/prctl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>
#include <signal.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

char *module_tag = (char *)"loader";

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

static const int threadCount = 8;

static std::atomic<bool> finished { false };

static void sigfcn(int signum)
{
    struct sigaction sig;
    sig.sa_handler = sigfcn;
    sigaction(SIGINT, &sig, NULL);
    const char *msg = "Loader: Received Control-C\n";
    ssize_t res = write(2, msg, strlen(msg));
    finished = true;
}

void func(int threadNum)
{
    char buf[128];
    snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "thread%d", threadNum);
    prctl(PR_SET_NAME, buf);
    while (!finished) {
        for (volatile int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
            if (finished) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Thread %d finished (2)\n", threadNum);
                return;
            }
            if (threadNum & 2) {
                std::this_thread::yield();
            }
        }
        if (threadNum & 1) {
            usleep(threadNum * 100);
        }
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "Thread %d finished (1)\n", threadNum);
}

int main(int ac, char **av)
{
    struct sigaction sig;
    sig.sa_handler = sigfcn;
    sigaction(SIGINT, &sig, NULL);

    std::thread threads[threadCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++) {
        threads[i] = std::thread(func, i);
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "Waiting until finished:\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Index %d, waiting\n", i);
        if (threads[i].joinable()) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Index %d, joining\n", i);
            threads[i].join();
            fprintf(stderr, "Index %d, joined\n", i);
        }
        fprintf(stderr, "Index %d, done waiting\n", i);
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "done waiting, killing procstat\n");

    return 0;
}
```

When successful, the output looks like:

```
Waiting until finished:
Index 0, waiting
Index 0, joining
^CLoader: Received Control-C
Thread 7 finished (2)
Thread 1 finished (2)
Thread 4 finished (2)
Thread 2 finished (2)
Thread 6 finished (2)
Thread 0 finished (2)
Thread 3 finished (2)
Index 0, joined
Index 0, done waiting
Index 1, waiting
Index 1, joining
Index 1, joined
Index 1, done waiting
Index 2, waiting
Index 2, joining
Index 2, joined
Index 2, done waiting
Index 3, waiting
Index 3, joining
Index 3, joined
Index 3, done waiting
Index 4, waiting
Index 4, joining
Index 4, joined
Index 4, done waiting
Index 5, waiting
Index 5, joining
Thread 5 finished (1)
Index 5, joined
Index 5, done waiting
Index 6, waiting
Index 6, joining
Index 6, joined
Index 6, done waiting
Index 7, waiting
Index 7, joining
Index 7, joined
Index 7, done waiting
done waiting, killing procstat
```

When it fails,

```
Waiting until finished:
Index 0, waiting
Index 0, joining
^CLoader: Received Control-C
Thread 4 finished (2)
Thread 3 finished (2)
Thread 0 finished (2)
Thread 6 finished (2)
Thread 5 finished (1)
Thread 2 finished (2)
Thread 1 finished (2)
Thread 7 finished (2)
```

Does anyone have an idea on where to go next?  Or, can anyone see where I screwed up?

Clearly, I've put a ton of printf()s in.  We don't have GDB on the ARM, so I can't go that way (and I can't run a remote gdb).

I've looked in `/proc/\<pid\>/task/` and verified the threads indeed go away.

I've looked in "perf top" and get the following:

| Overhead | symbol |
| --- | --- |
| 41.53% | __libc_csu_init |
| 25.30% | call*weak*_fn |
| 24.87% | register_*tm_*clones |
| 8.30% | _init |

[image]

Which are all in glibc.

I've also looked at the output of htop.

I was expecting it to always terminate my program.  When it hangs, I need to kill it from another terminal, or suspend and kill %1.

Comment: _Minimality check:_ Have you made this as simple as possible to debug? You do need `threadCount` to be 8? The problem does not occur at 7? 6? (etc.)

Comment: I've run with threadCount as low as 2.  The program was intended to test something else, but this issue got in the way.  The printf's were added later.  Test cycle for the ARM is close to 40 minutes - 20 to build our system and 20 to download and reflash.  Specifically, I tried 2, 4, and 8.  I saw the problem at all 3 of those.  I also added a delay between the create loop and the join loop, and it had no affect.

Comment: Adding a parameter for #threads, I tried with both 1 and 2.  Both sometimes succeeded, and sometimes failed.  I tried 1 on X86, and it consistently works correctly.

Comment: In both your calls to `sigaction`, you've only initialized the `sa_handler` field, but the `sa_flags` and `sa_mask` fields are uninitialized garbage.  The results are not going to be very predictable.

Comment: The `if (threads[i].joinable())` test looks suspicious to me.  Why are you testing to see if the thread is joinable?  Is there any reason why it wouldn't be?  And if there is, how do you handle the graceful shutting down of a non-joinable thread?

Comment: Check that `std::atomic<bool>::is_lock_free()` is `true` on your platform, otherwise you are not allowed to modify one from within a signal handler.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: AFAIK, the only ways for a `std::thread` not to be joinable is if it was created with the default constructor, or if it has already been joined or detached.  None of those is the case here, so I think `joinable()` will just always return `true`.

Comment: @NateEldredge Or if it has been moved-from. (FWIW: I also thought that `if` looked suspicious, but I concluded it's probably a red herring in this case, as it should always return `true`.)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is *the* bug causing your issues, but it's certainly *a* bug.

In your calls to `sigaction`, you only initialize the `sa_handler` field of your `struct sigaction`.  But the `sa_flags` and `sa_mask` fields are also used.  You are leaving them filled with garbage, so it's hard to guess what your `sigaction` calls are really doing.

I don't offhand see a way that this could cause the behavior you are seeing, but I also don't know precisely what `sigaction` does with all possible weird combinations of flags, nor the effect of masking signals you didn't intend to (some of which may be used internally by the pthreads library).  So fix this first, and if the problem persists, at least you'll have ruled out one possible cause.

Read the `sigaction(2)` man page carefully to see what it does.  I suspect you are going to want `sig.sa_flags = 0; sigemptyset(&sig.sa_mask);`.  Also, it is unnecessary to call `sigaction` again within the signal handler; the default with `sigaction` (unlike `signal`) is that the handler is not changed when the signal is raised.

Comment: Thanks all.  The resolution was the memset() for the sigaction.  It's working fine now.  Also, as to the comment about is_lock_free(), it is on my platform.

Comment: @DaveGotwisner: Glad that fixed it!  For future reference, valgrind catches this bug ("syscall param points to uninitialized bytes"), and even if you don't have valgrind available on your ARM target device, your test case would work on your Linux development box.